# A question about improper integrals

Tags: integration

"A function f is integrable on the interval $[a,b]$. If the function was $f^2$, it would still be integrable on $[a,b]$. However, this statement is not valid for improper integrals." why so?

Now I contemplate on this question, checked textbooks and it says "improper integral has 2 properties;
1-)involving unbounded intervals of integration
2-)involving infinitely many discontinuities"

I think it is not about the first rule since bounds are the same all the time. But, please do not mind me if it is nonsense, I think that maybe there is a function that its squared form has infinitely many discontinuities whereas its normal form has no problem. Can you please answer this question? and if there is such a function it would be marvelous if you can show it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$. Then

$$ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \text{ d}x  = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\varepsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \text{ d}x = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} (2 - 2 \sqrt{\varepsilon})= 2.$$

But, now $f^2(x) = 1/x$ and:

$$ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x} \text{ d}x  = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\varepsilon}^1 \frac{1}{x} \text{ d}x = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+ } (- \ln \varepsilon) \to \infty.$$

There's your counterexample. This falls under the category of improper integrals of *unbounded functions*. There's an infinite discontinuity at $0$ for both $f$ and $f^2$ and the functions blow up there.

Comment: Thank you so much, man.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can click the tick button (green when clicked) if you feel like this answer (or any other answers here) have answered your question.

Comment: I have a question about the example. Actually, my major is not mathematics and some of the notations and their usage is new to me. Could you please tell me what exactly we did when we added limit when epsilon approaches 0 from right before the integral symbol and also we changed lower bound as epsilon. ( I only know a bit about epsilon from the limit definition.)

Comment: I have added another equality above, please have a look. The integral with the limit $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ (approaching $0$ from the right) is a definition. We give that definition to make sense of these improper integrals. We define it this way because evaluating them directly simply doesn't make sense. Evaluating the second integral directly gives $\int_0^1 1/x \text{ d}x = - \ln 0$ which is undefined. So we say, hmm what happens if we get really close to $0$ but not $0$ itself. Hence, the usage of limits going to $0$.

Comment: That is okay now, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to mix up two different things. A function $f$ can be Riemann integrability on *closed intervals only* by definition. A known theorm states that if $f,g$ are Riemann integrable on a closed integrval $[a,b]$ then the product $f\cdot g$ is also integrable there.

However, improper integral is basically a limit. Improper integrals are not defined inside a closed set, so we cant talk about Riemann integrability of improper integrals, because they do not fit the definition.

Comment: Yeah, it perplexed me because wherever I lookup for the topic "Improper integral",  I did not see any expression with any interval [a,b].  But I did not come up with this question, it is written in this way so, could the question be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For Riemann integrals over a compact $[a,b]$, the integrability of $ f^2 $ comes from the fact that
$ f$ is bounded by $ M$
and
$$\forall (x,y)\in[a,b]^2\;\;$$
$$ |f^2(x)-f^2(y)|=$$
$$|f(x)+f(y)||f(x)-f(y)|\le 2M|f(x)-f(y)|.$$

so, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partage $ P$ such that
$$U(f^2,P)-L(f^2,P)\le$$
$$ 2M\Bigl(U(f,P)-L(f,P)\Bigr)<\epsilon$$

But for improper integrals, there is no reason that $$\lim_{x\to b^-}\int_a^xf^2(t)dt$$
exists if
$$\lim_{x\to b^-}\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
exists. for example, take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\;\;,a=0\;\;,b=1$$

Comment: First of all, thank you for your precious effort. I researched the proof for the integrability of f^2 of a function f on this site and saw a similar proof as you wrote in the first part, do not know if it was your writing, but same thing happens. My major is not mathematics and I am kinda having troubles while comprehending it. Is there a chance for you to clarify it a bit? if it is possible.

Comment: @prozgoret You want me to clarify which part of the answer ? about 2M ?

Comment: the first part like Riemann integrals over a compact [a,b], the integrability of f^2

Comment: @prozgoret I just added some lines. Do you know Cauchy criteria for Riemann integrability.